# Docker compose and dockerfile / .htaccess problem

Tags: docker, apache, server, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im few days in one project where I have a task of using Docker. After following few tutorials I find the easy way of deploying my LAMP server using `docker-compose` that looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    php-httpd:
        image: php:7.3-apache
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - "./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html"

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5.2
        volumes:
            - mariadb-volume:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            TZ: "Europe/Rome"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
            MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - 'mariadb:db'
        ports:
            - 8081:80

volumes:
    mariadb-volume:
```

Now after my app is in middle of development i find a problem that I need to edit the `.htaccess`  to turn on mod_rewrite and add some rules for REST API.

All solutions that I find are mentioning that I should add RUN command in `dockerfile` similar to this:

```
FROM httpd:alpine

# Copy .htaccess into DocumentRoot
COPY ./.htaccess /var/www/html/

RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

But I dont have that file, and offical documentation is of no help for me.

All I do is `sudo docker-compose up -d` to run my images. So question is:

**In what stage, how and where should I add this file to make it work.**

I know is possible cose I find this statement in one tutorial:

> Next time around, we'll create a more complicated docker-compose.yml
> file, one that works in conjunction with a Dockerfile.

But there was no followup on this.

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

**Also I know I can access PHP image with: `docker exec -it linuxconfig_php-httpd_1 bash`.
Maybe I can do something with that?**

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Docker is a layered file system, You can use one image and make modifications to it to create another image, which you can then push to your private Docker Registry or public dockerhub. To, create a custom image with your .htaccess changes, you will create a file named  "Dockerfile". You will then place the Dockerfile in the same directory  where your modified .htaccess

**Dockerfile content**

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

**Create Image:**

```
docker build -t custom-php:7.3-apache .
```

This will create a new image name (custom-php:7.3-apache). You can then use this new image in your docker-compose.yml file and when deployed, the container will have the updated .htaccess

2. You may mount the .htaccess to the desired path by using *volumes* option  as shown below

.

```
php-httpd:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - "./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html"
        - "./.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess"
```

I prefer #2 as you can edit .htaccess rules without rebuilding the image.

Comment: Thanks for the time, still trying to find out what I need in .htaccess but il go with 2nd option, but not sure where should I put new .htaccess file to be mounted in that volume.

Comment: I have put it in root next to composer file, he mounted it in root of the public folder, but it appeared empty. And im getting Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Just to report, I didnt have mode rewrite modul on in php, I managed to turn it on with a2enmod rewrite but htaccess is still loaded empty in root. And has no effect. I will try later first option...

Comment: try using absolute paths instead of relative paths in your volumes: section

Comment: Changing paths doesn't help, I get erros about volumes, and when trying to go with option 1 I get :  `=> ERROR [2/2] RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf                                                                                                                    0.5s
------
 > [2/2] RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
#5 0.522 sed: can't read /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory` So im still stuck... So much for "docker simplicity..."

Comment: I thought that the issue was .haccess but apparently it is not finding httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

In Dockerfile add "RUN a2enmod rewrite"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).